# Integral of $\frac1{|x|^3}$ on a circular segment

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

How can I evaluate
$$\int \int _C |(x,y)|^{-3} dx dy$$
Where $C$ is the part between the chord $AB$ and the arc $AB$, and $|(x,y)| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$? The radius of the circle is $R$.

I tried using polar coordinates, but I can’t find a way to represent $C$ with polar coordinates.

[image: A]

Comment: Isn't the field [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force), i.e. the integral does not depend on the path provided the winding number around $(0,0)$ is the same?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts What field?

Comment: @aschepler The user is talking about the vector field in the OP: $(x,y)\implies x\hat \imath+y\hat\jmath$

Comment: Try using $\int_C=\int_A-\int_B$ where $A$ is the region under the arc and the $x$ axis, and $B$ is the region under the chord and $x$ axis.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Can you please provide some more explanation? I don’t see how to relate the integral on $C$ to an integral on a loop.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari I’m not sure how to express the triangle with vertices $A, B, (0,0)$ in polar coordinates such that after changing the variables I’ll be able to use Fubini's theorem. I can only get to $\{(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta): (r, \theta) \in \{(x,y): y\in [\frac{\pi}3, \frac{2\pi}3], x\le \frac{y-b}a\}\}$ for $a,b$ such that the line $AB$ is represented by $y = ax + b$.

Comment: @רוירז In your last comment, that should be $\theta \in \left[\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3}\right]$ or $y \in \left[ \sin \frac{\pi}{6}, \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \right] = \left[ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$. I think Laxmi is suggesting just proceeding in rectangular coordinates.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari aschepler I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part of doing this in polar coordinates is the chord $AB$. Triangle $OAB$ is isosceles, so its angles $\angle OAB$ and $\angle OBA$ are both $75^\circ = \frac{5 \pi}{12}$. If $P$ is a point on segment $AB$ then from triangle $OBP$ with $OB = R$ and $\angle OBP = \angle OBA$, we have

$$ \angle POB + \angle OBP + \angle BPO = \pi $$

$$ \angle BPO = \frac{7 \pi}{12} - \angle POB $$

And from the law of sines,

$$ \frac{OB}{\sin \angle BPO} = \frac{OP}{\sin \angle OBP} $$

$$ OP = R\, \frac{\sin\left(\frac{7 \pi}{12} - \angle POB\right)}{\sin \frac{7 \pi}{12}} $$

If $\theta$ is the usual counter-clockwise angle from the $+x$-axis, then $\angle POB = \theta - \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $OP$ is the needed lower bound of $r$, so the original integral becomes

$$ \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \int_{R \sin(3 \pi/4 - \theta) / \sin(7 \pi/12)}^R r^{-3} r\, dr\, d\theta $$

Answer (score 2):

The function over which you are integrating is rotationally symmetric around the origin $(0,0)$, thus we can rotate the coordinate system in such a ways that $A$, $B$ are at $\pm15^\circ$ from an axis and, say, $x=\mathrm{const}$ for points on $\gamma$. One such rotation is such that

$$\begin{align}
A &= (\cos 15^\circ, \sin 15^\circ) = (\cos(\pi/12), \sin(\pi/12)) \\
&= \tfrac14 (\sqrt6+\sqrt2, \sqrt6-\sqrt2) =:(c,s)\\
B &= (\cos 15^\circ, -\sin 15^\circ) = (c,-s)
\end{align}$$
and all points in the chord have $x=\cos15^\circ = c$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\iint_C |(x,y)|^{-3}dxdy
&= \int_{+\sin(\pi/12)}^{-\sin(\pi/12)}  \frac{dy}{(y^2+\cos^2(\pi/12))^{3/2}} \\
&= \int_{+s}^{-s} \frac{dy}{(y^2+c^2)^{3/2}} \\
&= \frac{y}{c^2(y^2+c^2)^{1/2}} \Big|_{y=s}^{y=-s}\\
&= \frac{-2s}{c^2(s^2+c^2)^{1/2}} = -2\frac{s}{c^2} \\
&= -2 \frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{2+\sqrt3}
\end{align}$$
where in the second-last line we use $s^2+c^2=1$.